# How do I get around refreshing my videos?

Tags: javascript, php

I am making a messaging system and I recently added file uploads, and I refresh the messages every 1.5 seconds Here is my function :

```
function load_messages(){
    var id = document.getElementById('group_id').value;
    var fullurl = "loadmessages.php?id=" + id;
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("GET",fullurl,false);
      request.onload = function(){
          if(request.status == 200){
              document.getElementById("groupchat").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          }
      }
      request.send();
  };
  setInterval(load_messages, 1500);
```

I think the problem is that it keeps refreshing it there for I can't view it. How do I get around that?

Comment: You may need to rethink how you are doing things here. Maybe try to append only the new messages, instead of load all the messages.

Comment: How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I concur with @FelippeDuarte. Look into [The WebSockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) which is an alternative to the HTTP protocol. It enables you to keep an open connection between server and client.

Comment: If php load messages checks for new messages you could use AJAX and JSON to send a simple response if there are new messages or not then perform your load messages function, this way it's only triggered when needed.